# Cordova running / installing on multiple devices at once

Tags: cordova

Does anyone know if it is possible to run or install an app to multiple devices at once via the cordova cli ?

Currently I have to run the following commands in order to run on multiple devices

```
cordova run --target=XXXXXXXXXX

cordova run --target=yyyyyyyyyy

cordova run --target=zzzzzzzzzz
```

Looking for something like

`cordova run --target={zzzzzzzzzz yyyyyyyyyy zzzzzzzzzz}`

or

`cordova run --target=all`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came up with the same issue and got it working for android (use the same logic for other platforms) by using a shell script :

```
deviceLst=$(adb devices | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')

IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$deviceLst"

cd cordova

for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    cordova run android --target=$element
done

cd ..
```

Where `cd cordova` is the folder containing the platforms.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Can someone translate this to the Windows .bat format please?

Comment: Does not work for iOS since there's no adb. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this, is combining the two commands:

```
cordova run android --target=XXXXX && cordova run android --target=YYYY
```

Comment: How do I see the names of the available targets?

Comment: @Peter-Pan `adb devices`

Comment: Use only one `&` between commands.  Two `&&` will cause the second command to not launch if the first one fails.